# How to send list of objects via Post to our server dynamically

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

if its single object am able to send but how to send list of objects dynamically using json serialization and deserializtion and creating modal.this should be json string
[{"city_id":"1","state_name":"state1"},{"city_id":"1","state_name":"22"}].
For sending single object my code is below

```
NSString *cityId=@"1";
NSString *statNam=@"state1";
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"city_id",@"state_name",nil];
NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:cityId,statNam,nil];
NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];


NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDictionary options:0 error:&error];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", jsonString);
in NSLog my jsonString is  {"city_id":"1","state_name":"state1"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate your collection object add it into another mutable container then pass it as a immutable collection to `NSJSONSerialization`.
 I assume your list of data `yourActualCollect` is array of dictionary .

```
 NSMutableArray *yourDynamicModelArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    for(int indexNumber = 0; indexNumber < [yourActualCollect count]; indexNumber++){
        NSString *cityId = [[yourActualCollect objectAtIndex:indexNumber] objectForKey@"city_id"];
        NSString *statNam = [[yourActualCollect objectAtIndex:indexNumber] objectForKey@"state_name"];;
        NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"city_id",@"state_name",nil];
        NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:cityId,statNam,nil];
        NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];
        [yourDynamicModelArray addObject:jsonDictionary];
    }

    NSError *error;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:[NSArray arrayWithArray:yourDynamicModelArray] options:0 error:&error];
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@", jsonString);
```